# Unable to invoke Task module in MS Teams botbuilder bot via adaptive card

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have been trying to invoke the task module using adaptive card in Microsoft Teams bot by modifying the echo bot sample from botbuilder framework v1.3 in nodejs. I'm using the TeamsActivityHandler as instructed by the docs. Normal buttons seems to work fine, but the button type with task/fetch doesn't seems to be working as expected. Here is the card json:

```js
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "TaskModule Card",
          "wrap": true
      },
      {
          "type": "ActionSet",
          "actions": [
              {
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Invoke",
                  "data": {
                    "msteams": {
                      "type": "task/fetch"
                    }
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

When I click the button, it does not send any data back to the bot's backend to trigger handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch() method. Even the button animation that makes it gray while making call to the backend is not happening here.

Even the same happens with the example provided here [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs). How to fix this issue?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're running the Teams sample without modification and it is not working?

Comment: @jaison M - We also see this issue with [bot task module nodejs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs) sample. C# sample is working fine, we will check and get back to you.

Comment: @AP01 I modified the sample as per instructed, updated the .env file with the Ids. Everything else seems to work fine except the task module.

Comment: Based on the comment from the Teams rep, it seems that Teams has also noticed this issue, and they're taking a look at it.

Comment: @JaisonM - Can you confirm if your issue is similar to https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/656?

Comment: @JaisonM - We checked the sample today again and it seems to be working fine. Can you please check and confirm the same. We have run this sample as is without changing anything - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - Yes, I'm facing a similar issue that was mentioned above. I'll check the sample once and will let you know

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - I re-did all the steps given here - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs, but still same result. The bot sends the adaptive card but the button does not trigger the task module

Comment: We are not able to repro locally, we have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thanks.

Comment: Engineering team and we are unable to repro this issue, could you please provide test account where this issue reproducible?